# KSQL queries have strange keys infront of the key value

Tags: ksqldb

I have created a stream like this:

```
CREATE STREAM TEST1 WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='TEST_1',VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

I then query the stream like this via CLI:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST1;
```

The results are looking like this:

```
1571225518167 | \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0006key | 7 | 7 | blue
```

I wonder why the key is formated like this. Is my query somehow wrong? The value should be like this:

```
1571225518167 | key | 7 | 7 | blue
```

Comment: So your question is just curiosity why are there additional spaces rendered before the key? Or are you seeing problems as a result of this?

Comment: SO somehow removed the "special chars" from the post and i didnt noticed. I edited them in, as they appear in my IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key is in Avro format, which KSQL doesn't support yet.

If you have control over the data producer, write the key in string format (e.g. Kafka Connect use the `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter`). If not, and you need to use the key e.g. for driving a KSQL table you'd need to re-key the data using KSQL:

```
CREATE STREAM TEST1_REKEY AS SELECT * FROM TEST1 PARTITION BY my_key_col
```